# Discrepancy in DNS resolution between Mac and Windows in Java application using org.minidns.hla

Tags: java, dns

I have a java application which uses org.minidns to do an SRV lookup on a service and domain. The dns resolution is successful when running on the MacOS, but when running on my Windows VM (accessed over VPN on company private subnet), the DNS resolution is unsuccessful.

When issuing a ping from the Windows VM to the target server using the host name, it can resolve the IP address. I'm not very experienced in setting up DNS settings, so I was wondering if someone can help me rule out some obvious root causes.

Code block under question:

```
public List<InetSocketAddress> resolveSrv(String service, String domain) throws RuntimeException, IOException {
    log.info("Attempting to DNS resolve {}.{}", service, domain);

    return ResolverApi.INSTANCE.resolveSrv(service + "." + domain)
            .getSortedSrvResolvedAddresses()
            .stream().map(resolvedSrvRecord -> {
                try {
                    return new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(resolvedSrvRecord.srv.target.ace),
                            resolvedSrvRecord.srv.port);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```